# Obtaining back incidence data from cumulative data?

Tags: r, diff, cumsum

I have a dataframe for which I have date data and cumulative counts.
I am trying to do a *reverse of cumsum* to get the daily counts **but** also getting the counts per group.
I am trying to go from dataframe A to dataframe B.
I am using R and `tidyr`.

Here is the code :

```
df <- data.frame(cum_count = c(5, 14, 50, 5, 14, 50),
                 state = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "NY", "NY", "NY"),
                 Year = c(2012:2014, 2012:2014))
```

```
Dataframe A
  cum_count   state Year
1         5 Alabama 2012
2        14 Alabama 2013
3        50 Alabama 2014
4         5      NY 2012
5        14      NY 2013
6        50      NY 2014
```

```
Dataframe B
  cum_count   state Year
1         5 Alabama 2012
2         9 Alabama 2013
3        36 Alabama 2014
4         5      NY 2012
5         9      NY 2013
6        36      NY 2014
```

I have tried using the diff function :

```
df <- df %>%group_by(state)%>%
      mutate(daily_count = diff(cum_count))
```

But I get

> Error: Column `daily_count` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

Let me know what you think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` returns `length` one less than the original length and `mutate` requires the output column to have the same `length` as the original (or length 1 which can be recycled).  We can append a value possibly `NA` or the `first` value of 'cum_count'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(state)%>%
  mutate(daily_count = c(first(cum_count), diff(cum_count)))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   state [2]
#  cum_count state    Year daily_count
#      <dbl> <fct>   <int>       <dbl>
#1         5 Alabama  2012           5
#2        14 Alabama  2013           9
#3        50 Alabama  2014          36
#4         5 NY       2012           5
#5        14 NY       2013           9
#6        50 NY       2014          36
```

---

Or for this purpose, use `lag` and subtract from the column itself

```
df %>%
    group_by(state)%>%
    mutate(daily_count = replace_na(cum_count - lag(cum_count), first(cum_count)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations!